# Cannot see files present on server when connecting via SFTP?

Tags: ssh, sftp, filezilla

I am not able to see the files present on the server using Filezilla ftp client. I am using SFTP connection. I am able to connect to the server. I can see only the directories but not the files. I have also enabled the Server>Force showing hidden files Option. When I connect the server using winScp I can see the files. Thank you in advance. Any help is appreciated. [Note: All the files are php files only. Not sure if its related with .php extension]

Comment: Non-programming questions are offtopic here.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp: How should I move this question to other site. I do not have permissions. Thought it was something related.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp : Thankyou.

Comment: @veer712 Hi, please don't use the Server tag anymore. It clearly says: DO NOT USE. So please follow that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the FileZilla FTP tool. Navigate through View > Filename filters >Directory listing filters and uncheck all the checked options in remote filters and click on apply button.

Comment: WOW, it worked. Thanks a ton @kevin6bailley